# Drupal 7 Views Slideshow and Media with MediaElement.js <video> tag

Tags: video, drupal-7, view, slideshow, mediaelement.js

I've got a drupal simplistic website on which I wonderfully made working view slideshow. On some other pages, I'v got some blocks with video included via the  tag through MediaElement.js and Media drupal modules.

Everything is working so fine ! But as soon as I place a views slideshow AND a `<video>` tag  on the same page, the video works ok, but the slide show does not anymore, it only shows the first result set of the view.

Has anyone experimented this problem ? I'm pretty sure (but could be wrong!) it's a question of javascript getting appropriated by one module (MediaElement.js) without getting back the hand to the other (actually Views Slideshow uses jQuery.cycle) but I can't get it working !

Thanks for reading ;)

Answer (score 0):

Damn...

If anybody comes to this, it's just because in /sites/all/libraries/mediaelement the file "mediaelement.js" should be not be in this root directory, but you have to extract ALL the files and folder so mediaelement.js is in the "build" subdirectory (so /sites/all/libraries/mediaelement/mediaelement.js).

Hope it helps, as usual !